# Relative files on c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to open some openGL shaders on my C++ application. My application is separated on two abstraction layers: the graphics engine (which uses openGL) and the actual application logic. I want the graphics engine to be as recyclable as possible[1] (for other projects).

The problem is that if I define the shader file's path relatively (for instance `#define FOO_FRAG_SHADER "shaders/foo.frag"`) the program is not able to find it, as this directory is relative to the graphics engine's path and not the application's path. For the reason commented above [1], I really don't want to specify it's directory relative to the application's dir, as it becomes application dependent.

Therefore, my question is: Is there anyway to specify a directory relative to a file which specifies it?

Comment: ***Is there anyway to specify a directory relative to a file which specifies it rather than to the executable?*** It should have no relation to the executable.

Comment: Relative directory paths are relative to the programs working directory from where you running it, not where the executable actually resides.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are resolved with respect to the *working directory* of the process, which is not necessarily the location of the executable itself. For example, if you start your program like this

```
/user/oier/bin/> ./a.out
```

then relative paths are resolved in relation to `/user/oier/bin`. However, if you start it like this

```
/user/oier/> bin/a.out
```

then relative paths are resolved in relation to `/user/oier`.

There are two common approaches to solving this problem without hard-coding the location of your files:

- Pass a command line parameter specifying the base path for the graphics engine, or
- Use an environment variable to specify the location of the graphics engine

If the files in question are small, and there is a possibility that each application might want to supply a private copy of it, a third approach is to copy the files in question to a folder under your application's `bin`, and use a relative reference based on the location of the copy.

Comment: Let's see if I have understood your solution correctly (the second one looks reasonable). I've looked how ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES work in C++. So Before executing the code I need to set a environment  variable indicating the path of the shaders. For example: `user@mySystem:$ FOO_APP_SHADERS=whatever/someotherdir/shaders` then I need to query it on my graphics engine with `getenv()`, so that by adding "/foo.frag" at the end of it I can access the file

Comment: You may want to have a fallback default path if the environment variable is not set.

Comment: @oierlauzi Right, that's the approach. Most systems let you define environment variables as part of some sort of per-user/per-system start-up script, so you would have to configure `FOO_APP_SHADERS` once during the installation of your library.